# Report with percentage field and no groupings - how to export in a different format?

Tags: reporting

My customer has a report that pulls a percentage field, which displays in the report as 10% and exports to excel as 10. They then take that data and do calculations in excel, so they want it to export as .1 instead of 10. Because there aren't any groupings in the report, I can't make a formula, so I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a formula return a percentage, what it does behind the scenes is multiply the number by 100.  So the number for this would be .10, when you tell it to return a formula it returns 10% because they multiplied the .10 by 100.

So in your case, if they want the export to return .1, then they need to change the formula to return a number and not a percentage.  Then it will export it as the decimal as you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear in how I wrote my question. The percentage is just a field that is pulled into the report and I can't use formulas in the report because it isn't summarized.

Comment: If the percentage field is a custom field, then just change it to number.  If it is a standard field, then make a formula field that divides it by 100 and pull that into the report.

Comment: Yes, I am still on the rookie side and also blonde. :) That was too easy - thank you so much!!!!! It was a managed package field, so I added a formula field and hid it from the page. THANK YOU!